# Why isn't my canvas object changing color after setInterval() is called?

Tags: javascript, oop, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to get my canvas object to change color automatically every 0.25 seconds during an animation when the `setInterval()` but instead it changes every time I press a key down. Here is my code to execute the animation.

```
// Creating the shape
class Planet extends CompoundDrawable{
constructor(context,x = 0, y = 0, fillStyle = "#000", strokeStyle = "transparent", lineWidth = 0, deltas = new Map(), shapes = new Set()){
    super(context,x,y,fillStyle,strokeStyle,lineWidth,deltas);

    const mainPlanetShape = new Circle(context,0,0,fillStyle,strokeStyle,0,new Map(),80);
    this.shapes.add(mainPlanetShape);

    const largePlanetCrater = new Circle(context,randomBetween(-23,23),randomBetween(-23,23),"darkgrey","transparent",0,new Map(),11);
    this.shapes.add(largePlanetCrater);

    for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        const planetCrater = new Circle(context,randomBetween(-23,23),randomBetween(-24,24),"darkgrey","transparent",0,new Map(),randomBetween(3,6));

        this.shapes.add(planetCrater);
    }
  }
}

// Placing the shape on Canvas and animating it
function startAnimationS(){
const animationSObjects = new Set();

const animationSPlanet = new Planet(context,-100,canvas.height/2,colourChanger(),"transparent",10,new Map());
// Context, x, y , fillStyle, strokeStyle, lineWIdth, new Map
animationSObjects.add(animationSPlanet);
//Setting up properties to animate
setTimeout(() => 
{
    animationSPlanet.deltas.set("x",400);
    animationSPlanet.deltas.set("angle",3);
}, 1000)
setTimeout(() => 
{
    animationSPlanet.deltas.delete("x");
    animationSPlanet.deltas.delete("fillStyle");
},4000)

// Perform the animation
function animationS(){
    requestId = requestAnimationFrame(animationS);
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

    const diffSeconds = (Date.now() - lastTime) / 1000;
    lastTime = Date.now();

    if(diffSeconds > 0){
        for(const animationSObject of animationSObjects)
        {
            if(animationSObject.x >= canvas.width/2.2)
            {
               animationSObject.x = 10;
            }
            animationSObject.applyAnimation(diffSeconds);
            animationSObject.draw();
        }
     }
  }
animationS();
}

let counter = 0;
let intervalInterchange;
//Colour changing function
function colourChanger()
{
counter = counter - 10;

    let colour1 = 110 - counter;
        colour2 = 90 - counter;
        colour3 = 50 - counter;
        colour4 = 0.5;

    let finalColour = "rgba(" + Math.round(colour1) + "," + Math.round(colour2) + "," + Math.round(colour3) + "," + Math.round(colour4) + ")";
    return finalColour;
}
if(intervalInterchange === "undefined")
{
    setInterval(colourChanger,250);
} else {
    clearInterval(intervalInt);
    intervalInt = undefined;
}

// Calling the function by the event 'keydown'
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
stopAnimation();
if(e.keyCode > 64 && e.keyCode < 91){
    if(e.keyCode == 83)
    {
        startAnimationS();
    }  else {
    alert("Please enter a letter between A and Z");
  }
});
```

Comment: `internalInterchange` is `undefined` (the literal value), not `"undefined"` (the string). Doing a strict comparison with the string will be false, which I assume is not what you want.

Comment: @Frxstrem Good spot, thank you, but the colour still will not change color when the animation is running. Only when I keep pressing the key 's' will the color slowly start to get lighter.

Comment: Please, indent your code correctly next time.

Comment: You never actually use the return value of the coulourChanger function in this snippet. Please, post a minimal verifiable example.

Comment: @Bálint Apologies, I have edited so it is now easier to read. I haven't actually used the return value as of yet in my code, perhaps that it is why it isn't working.

Comment: @Bálint Where would you suggest I use the return value, Iv'e attempted calling it instead of the function but it still makes no difference.

Comment: I don't know **because you don't show us where you want to change the color of whatevery ypu use**

Comment: @Bálint You mean change the colour of the shape? If so it's declared in the varialbe 'animationSPlanet'.

Comment: Also, I don't know what you edited on the question, but it' certainly not easier to read. Please, indent everythong after an openinf bracket one more than the line before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're dropping the return value of the `colourChanger` function. You can't expect the setInterval function to magically know what you want to use it for, so you need to do that yourself.

Instead of calling the `colourChanger` function directly in an interval, call an anonymus function and inside that change the color of the shape:

```
setInterval(function() {
    animationSPlanet.color = colourChanger(); // I still don't know how you store this thing's color.
}, 250);
```